# How to display current user's username in URL Flask

Tags: python, flask, url, routes, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to add my current user's username to my URL(route), but I keep on getting errors. I have tried many things as mentioned below but nothing is working. Here is my code:

```py
@app.route("/settings/<string:Users_username>" , methods=["GET", "POST"])
def settings(Users_username):
    user = Users.query.filter_by(username=Users_username)
    return render_template("settings.html", user=user )
```

Layout.html:

```
<a href="{{url_for('settings', Users_username = user.username )}}" target="_blank" 
rel="noopener noreferrer">Settings</a>
```

I get the error when I try to go to another page and 404 when I go to settings.

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError
>
> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'user' is undefined

[image]

MODELS.py

```py
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
   return Users.query.get(int(user_id))

class Users(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
```

Is something wrong in layout.html or my routes.html? This is basically a function, that  when settings  is clicked takes you to settings page and I want the username of the logged in user to appear in URL.When I change my layout.html, then I get

> 404 error: Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again

I have made sure user is logged in:`{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}`
I also tried changing routes.py as:

```py
@app.route("/settings/<string:Users_username>" , methods=["GET", "POST"])
def settings(Users_username):
    user = Users.query.filter_by(username=Users_username)
    return render_template("settings.html", user=user.username )
```

Rest is same (settings function). This change gave error:

> AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'username'

Comment: The formatting of this is a mess. Please don't format your text as code. Please [edit] the question to get it in shape

Comment: try this `user = Users.query.filter_by(username=Users_username).first()` in settings function

Comment: @faris404 I am still getting the    error  "user is undefined" while trying to access any other page and 404 not found error while trying to access settings page.

Comment: @faris404  is some thin wrong with .username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After  3 days of research and desire for answers, reading multiple articles watching countless videos, just randomly  tried this  in layout.html which worked!!

```
<a href="{{ url_for('user', Users_username = current_user.username ) }}" 
target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Settings</a>
```

Now no need for database queries in settings function!

Answer (score 0):

Try this `user = Users().query.filter_by(username=Users_username).first()`.

And you don't need to give a string as a converter type in your url because it is string by default. [Have a look here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/)

Comment: Nothing seems to be working. When I remove ".username" from url_for in layout.html, I get 404 error but atleast I am able to access other page

Comment: why is the error "user is undefined " showing up when I use "Users_username=user.username"

Answer (score 0):

@Reef is almost correct : In the function `settings(Users_username)` replace :

```
user = Users.query.filter_by(username=Users_username)
```

by

```
user = Users.query.filter_by(username=Users_username).first()
```

(or better `first_or_404()` is you are using Flask-Sqlalchemy)

Comment: Thank you but just a sec before I figured out the answer my self!

Comment: By the way I had tried this before none of it worked, the main error was " user is undefined" but I think most answers and commens were solution to 404. Settings function lacked .first() for which I am thankful to you all !